# Show loader inside Bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap card to design a dashboard. Since each card has individual data loading through ajax I want to show a loader inside the specific card where the data is being loaded. Below is my code

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card ">

                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                    </div>
                    <div id="bidStatusLoader" style='display:none' class="animationload">
                        <div class="osahanloading"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card ">

                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" />
```

Here is the script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
       ShowModal();
    });
  });

function ShowModal()
{
  //This will be an ajax call.Show Modal during call
  $("#bidStatusLoader").show();

}
```

When the button is clicked it will do some ajax operation and till that time I want to show the loader inside the card but not sure how to do that.

Here is the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qozvga1r/1/)

Using the loader from here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/creative-animated-loading-icon-in-html5-css3

Comment: I don't really understand the issue here. Can you explain a little better?

Comment: Sure so if you look at the fiddle and click on the button clickMe what I want is that a loader should come up inside the center of the first card. The data in each card will be refreshed separately so I want to provide a loader inside the card while the data is being loaded.

Comment: Right now the loader is hiding everything and loading on the main page..I just want it inside the first card.

Comment: I think you're missing the actual class. Currently you just have an ::after styling for that class. It's fixed here ->
https://jsfiddle.net/qozvga1r/6/

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can block the card UI also while the loader is loaded.